# get date from arabic string

Tags: regex

I have an Arabic string that shows date in Arabian with detail how can I get dd mm yyyy from that with regex

Ex:
`الأحد 21 مايو 2017 01:20 م`
i use this regex but doesn't work
`^\d{2} [\u0600-\u06FF] \d{4}`
what can i do ?

Comment: Use `\d{2} [\u0600-\u06FF]+ \d{4}` or `\b\d{2} [\u0600-\u06FF]+ \d{4}\b`

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
(\d{4}\ \d{2}:\d{2})
```

Will match `2017 01:20`

I guess you could play around with capture groups to get it in the right order if you want to use the result afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

The code is here. Arabic right to left should reverse the code.

```
\d\d\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d
```